# How do I use bootstrap 3 collapse for an accordion without data- markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use bootstrap collapse for an accordion without all of the `data-` attribute markup. I see it toggle on creation but I want the two anchors in panel-title to control collapse. I know how to do this manually with jQuery but I think that I should be able to do it with one call to `.collapse()`.

JS

```
$('.collapse').collapse();
//$('.t-title,.t-toggle').collapse(); // also tried this with no luck
```

HTML

```
<!-- notices start -->
<div class="row spaced" id="notice">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <!-- start update -->
      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="t-title" href="#notice-1">title</a>
            <a class="t-toggle" href="#notice-1">toggle</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="notice-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body"><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- / end update -->
      <!-- start update -->
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="t-title" href="#notice-2">title</a>
            <a class="t-toggle" href="#notice-2">toggle</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="notice-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- / end update -->
      <!-- start update -->
      <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="t-title" href="#notice-3">title</a>
            <a class="t-toggle" href="#notice-3">toggle</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="notice-3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- / end update -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might get some help if you put this into a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't leave `data-` markup aside, as the `collapse()` function **is made to initialize** the Collapse component, it's not an event trigger.

If you don't want to manually set every `data-toggle` attribute, you can at least use this line :

```
$('#accordion').find('.t-title, .t-toggle').attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
```

**[Bootply](http://bootply.com/98602)**