# How to initialize bootstrap 4.6 collapse with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, custom-data-attribute

[Bootstrap 4.6 docs mention](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/collapse/#via-javascript) that we can enable/initialize the collapse menu with eaither `data-` attributes or javascript. I assume `data-target` is still necessary to link a button to the collapsable element. This leaves me with `data-toggle="collapse"`, which I assume further is equivalent of the javascript initilization. So lets try it out:

```js
$("#demo").collapse() //doesn't work

$("#demo").collapse({
  toggle: false
}) //doesn't work either!!

$("#demo").collapse("toggle"); //doesn't do nothing
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <button id="mybtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am unable to initialize the collapse function through javascript alone. So my question is:

1. How to enable/initialize bootstrap 4.6 collapse without `data-toggle` attribute, using javascript? Note `data-target` is still allowed.
2. What does passing the options object in the initialization do? Especially what's the difference between passing `{toggle: false}` and `{toggle: true}`? Can I pass `{toggle: "collapse"}`?

Comment: I believe this may still apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121982/how-do-i-use-bootstrap-3-collapse-for-an-accordion-without-data-markup

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an action on your button like this :

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#demo").collapse("toggle");
  //console.log("toggle");
}, 200);

$('#mybtn').click(function(){
    $("#demo").collapse("toggle");
});
```

Another solution it's working perfectly for me:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <button id="mybtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
      $("#demo").collapse("toggle");
   });
</script>
```

The differences and the use of functions are well explained in the documentation : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/collapse/#via-javascript

Comment: But, this is not activation of bootstrap collapse. you are just manually triggering `toggle` on click event. javascript initialization should mimic `data-*` initialization, so there should not be a need to manually assign events.

Comment: I modified my answer and I added a JavaScript function named setTimeout which will allow you to trigger your event

Comment: Whats the point of adding a `setTimeout`? I still don't understand why we need jquery click to bind the toggle, bootstrap activation should bind that itself.

Comment: Delete the click event this will still work, we need setTimeout because your page must first be fully loaded for the instruction $ ("# demo"). Collapse ("toggle"); is executed.

Comment: If I delete the click event then nothing happens on pressing the `#mybtn` button. If you are using setimeout just to wait for loading the page then you are better off using `domcontentloaded` or `jquery ready function` and then force a css repaint to make it bulletproof.

Comment: I tried to edit my answer again, try to see the proposal, it works perfectly for me. Maybe I didn't quite understand your question.

Comment: Your last example works because you have `data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo"`. I want the code to work without `data-toggle` and without jquery `click`. You can keep `href` and `data-target`.

Comment: But if you remove `data-toggle`, you must do everything manually and add a click event, because the `data-target` option depends on the `data-toggle` option. For example, I can do everything with jquery or JavaScript without the `data- *` options everything will work perfectly.

Comment: How does `data-target` depend upon `data-toggle`? I thought they are independent. Secondly why doesn't `$("#demo").collapse();` bind the click event to toggle(i.e. initialises) as suggested by bootstrap docs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
// activates your content as a collapsible element
$('#myCollapsible').collapse();

$('#collapseButton').on('click', function() {
  // toggles a collapsible element to shown or hidden
  $('#myCollapsible').collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="collapseButton">Toggle Collapse (Shown On Load)</button>

<div id="myCollapsible">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...
  </div>
</div>
```

Use of `class="collapse"` and `{toggle: false}` makes the `collapse` hidden on load

```js
// activates your content as a collapsible element
$('#myCollapsible').collapse({toggle: false});

$('#collapseButton').on('click', function() {
  // toggles a collapsible element to shown or hidden
  $('#myCollapsible').collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="collapseButton">Toggle Collapse (Hidden On Load)</button>

<div class="collapse" id="myCollapsible">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. You are manually collapsing the menu with jquery click function. One, with your method you don't need `$('#myCollapsible').collapse();` because there's nothing getting activated. Two, when you initialize bootstrap carousel with `$('.carousel').carousel()`, you don't need to explicitly use `$('.carousel').carousel('next')`, the carousel just runs like it was initialized with `data-` attributes. Same should be true of the `collapse`.

Comment: @user31782: I dont understand your question then.  You asked, "How to enable/initialize bootstrap 4.6 collapse without data- attributes, using javascript". I didn't use `data-`  attribute. toggle needs a trigger right? without data attribute or js how are you going to specify which element to collapse.

Comment: I can still use `data-target` to specify which is the trigger button and the value of `data-target` will tell which elements need to be collapsed. I want to activate/enable/initialize the collapse menu without the jquery click. But, `$('#myCollapsible').collapse();` doesn't achieve that, which is what I don't understand.

Comment: @user31782: Look at the documentation, "Activates your content as a collapsible element." It doesn't set a parent which triggers the toggle event. I think you are confused with initialization and toggle.

Comment: The parent which triggers the toggle can be set via `data-target`, that's not an issue. if the only thing that js initialization does is _activating the content as collapsible_, then that's redundant, because you don't need to activate anything for the toggle to work.